# unable to find included dependencies for latest version of deep learning containers. is GCP no longer providing these?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform, google-dl-platform

I was trying to find included dependencies file for m99 and m100 release milestones as mentioned in below documentation page, but the last release milestone I could see is M96.

https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-containers/docs/choosing-container#included_dependencies